# How to use the cancelEl in a Backbone Modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, modal-dialog

I'm currently using this plugin for a modal: http://awkward.github.io/backbone.modal/

It comes with a `cancelEl` method to close the modal, and I am using it like so:

```
  var ActionModal = Backbone.Modal.extend({
    template: '#actionable-modal-template',
    cancelEl: '.bbm-btn-close'
  });
```

And here is what I am trying to do, written in pseudo code:

```
if (cancelEl.invoked) {
  // Do something
}
```

The psuedo code is based on the assumption that `cancelEl` causes clicking the backdrop of the modal, as well as the button, to close the modal.

How can I use the `cancelEl` method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `beforeCancel` or `cancel`

```
  var ActionModal = Backbone.Modal.extend({
    template: '#actionable-modal-template',
    cancelEl: '.bbm-btn-close',
    beforeCancel: function() {
       // stuff
    }
  });
```

Looking at the source code, `beforeCancel` can be used to *cancel* the modal close:

```
if (this.beforeCancel) {
  if (this.beforeCancel() === false) {
    return;
  }
}
```

And `cancel` can be used to implement more functionality:

```
if (typeof this.cancel === "function") {
  this.cancel();
}
```